# How do I set the HTTP request body with Wreq?

Tags: haskell, wreq

How can I set the request body when using `customMethod` https://hackage.haskell.org/package/wreq-0.5.2.1/docs/Network-Wreq.html#v:customMethod?

`post`, `put` etc accept a parameter for the body, however there is no such parameter for `customMethod`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`customPayloadMethod`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/wreq-0.5.2.1/docs/Network-Wreq.html#v:customPayloadMethod) to specify a custom method on a request with a postable body.

```hs
customPayloadMethod :: Postable a => String -> String -> a -> IO (Response ByteString)
```

There are a few other variations of this depending on your needs:

```hs
customPayloadMethodWith :: Postable a => String -> Options -> String -> a -> IO (Response ByteString) Source#
customHistoriedPayloadMethod :: Postable a => String -> String -> a -> IO (HistoriedResponse ByteString) Source#
customHistoriedPayloadMethodWith :: Postable a => String -> Options -> String -> a -> IO (HistoriedResponse ByteString)
```